# Fetch a web page dynamic data using jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I want to fetch the data from example.com/page.html. Here is the page.html when I get it's content using Chrome Browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
        <p>test 3</p>
    </div>
   <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the page.html when I get it's content using Ajax:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
    </div>
     <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the paragraphs are not there!

here is the Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/page.html',
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

I know that the paragraphs are generated using the script(test.js)and script.js is processed using Chrome JS Engine. So here is my question: How can I get the whole rendered page.html content via AJAX?

Comment: have your tried `.load()` of jquery? see [here](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: @Pirate Yes, I did and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the whole rendered page.html content via AJAX?

You can't.

Ajax is just the process of making an HTTP request and getting the result using client-side JS.

You need to do things that are not Ajax.

---

You need to either:

- Make the Ajax request and then follow it up by reproducing everything that the JS referenced by the page would do
- Inject the HTML into the browser in a way that lets the JS execute and then read the DOM from the browser (this can be dangerous if the injected code ends up interacting with your page in some ways).
- Build a web service which renders the page in a headless browser and then returns a serialised version of the DOM and then make an Ajax request to that web service.

Comment: I think the third suggestion is the way to go. Could you put a reference on how to do that? I was thinking of using Scrapy but I really wanna do this using Javascript.